# Mongoid: convert embedded document into referenced/own collection

Tags: ruby, mongodb, migration, mongoid

I need to convert an embedded document onto its own collection, so it can be referenced from another collection.

Lets suppose I have a `Parent` that embeds many `Childs`.
I was thinking of something along this:

```
Parent.all.each do |p|
 p.childs.all.each do |c|
  c.raw_attributes['parent_id'] = p.id
 end
 p.save! #will save parent and cascade persist all childs onto their own coll
end
```

Is this an option? Ideally I would run this in a console and I would only change mongoid mappings from `embed_*` to `has_*`, so I wouldn't need to change the rest of my code or use another collection as staging.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think, the code should look more like this (didn't test)

```
child_coll = Mongoid.database.collection('children')

Parent.all.each do |p|
  p.childs.all.each do |c|
    c.attributes['parent_id'] = p.id

    child_coll.insert c.attributes # save children to separate collection
  end

  p.childs = nil # remove embedded data
  p.save
end
```

After that, you can change your `embeds_many` to `has_many` and (hopefully) it should work well.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna give it a try!

Comment: FYI, I believe line 1 now should be: `child_coll =  Mongoid.client(:default).database.collection(:children)`

Comment: @ChipRoberson: it may very well be now, but 9 years ago, this API must've been different. AFK now, so if you're sure of that, go ahead and edit the post.

Answer (score 7):

too little rep to comment, but I think Sergio's (otherwise very helpful) answer may be outdated. With mongoid 3.0.5 I couldn't use

```
child_coll = Mongoid.database.collection('children')
```

but instead used

```
child_coll = Mongoid.default_session[:children]
```

which did the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

For me I need to remove the '_id' attribute before inserting otherwise I will get Duplicated key Error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated version of Sergio Tulentsev's approach with Pencilcheck's addition and an update of sbauch's correction.

First, leave the embeds_many/embedded_in statements in place in your models.

Second, run something like this block of code:

```
child_coll =  Mongoid.client(:default).database.collection(:children)
Parent.all.each do |p|
  p.childs.all.each do |c|
    dup = c.attributes
    dup['_id'] = nil
    dup['parent_id'] = p.id
    child_coll.insert_one dup # save children to separate collection
    c.destroy
  end
  p.childs = nil # remove embedded data
  p.save
end
```

Third, change your `embeds_many` to `has_many` and your `embedded_in` to `belongs_to`.

Fini.